# How to Update last added row based on user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, t-sql

I have a VB.NET WinForms Project that allows employees to log in, and register their Time-In, Time-Out and Food Break, connected to an SQL Server Database through a DataSet made from Visual Studio designer (This means all the database connections are being handled automatically, I have none "hardcoded", so that is not needed)
The Database has two tables, _tblUser for Users and _tblTime where the assistances are stored, both have a primary key (Id) and are linked through one.

In the user interface, theres 3 buttons:
Time-In, Time-Out, Food Break 
Each one, when clicked, should update the database. There is also a datagrid that shows only the records of the employee currently logged in

The first one, Time-In, is working fine using this query with the query Builder

```
INSERT INTO _tblTime ([ID EMPLOYEE], EMPLOYEE, DATE, TIMEIN)
VALUES (@ID_EMPLOYEE,@EMPLOYEE,@DATE,@TIMEIN)
```

then on code I pass the values

```
Private Sub _B3_TimeIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _B3_TimeIn.Click
    _tblTimeTableAdapter.InsertTimeIn(currentID, currentName, currentDate, currentTime)
End Sub
```

currentID and currentName are variables where the employee's currently logged in info is already stored
currentDate and currentTime store the system's date and time

But for the other two buttons, I need it to update the last row inserted **by the user** that is currently logged in, and that's where Im stuck.
First I tried selecting the last added row with:

```
UPDATE _tblTime SET FOODBREAK = @FOODBREAK WHERE (Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM _tblTime))
```

This works, but obviously leaves a big problem for multi-user scenario, for example, lets say User1 logs in, clicks on Time-In which adds a new row that has the Max Id, then logs out and works. Then User2 logs in, clicks on Time-In which adds a new row that now has the current Max Id, then logs out and goes to work. When User1 logs again to register their FOODBREAK, using the above query obviously registers the time to the row with Max Id which now belongs to User2.
So thats what I'm trying to do, to specifically update the last row of the currently logged user, and I don't know how.

I also tried

```
UPDATE _tblTime SET FOODBREAK = @FOODBREAK WHERE Id = @Param1
```

Then I pass the employee id (which is my linked key):

```
Private Sub _PB6_Comida_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _PB6_Comida.Click
    _tblTimeTableAdapter.UpdateComida1(currentTime, currentID)
```

This kind of works, but it updates the very first record of the employee rather than the last which is what I need

Comment: You need to get the PK of the inserted row. Either use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the command, or change the insert to `INSERT INTO tbl (whatever_columns) OUTPUT inserted.pk_column VALUES (inserted_values)`. Then use that PK in the `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options here.

Fix the approach you were using by filtering by `Employee`:

```
UPDATE _tblTime SET
    FOODBREAK = @FOODBREAK
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM _tblTime WHERE [ID EMPLOYEE] = @EMPLOYEE);
```

Or improve on the filter condition, say its the only record without a `Foodbreak` or the only record without a 'TimeIn', for that employee, you can filter by that.

```
UPDATE _tblTime SET
    FOODBREAK = @FOODBREAK
WHERE [ID EMPLOYEE] = @EMPLOYEE AND FOODBREAK IS NULL;
```